# iptables can't make http/https connection

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to configure a firewall with IPTables, the firewall sits in between the LAN and Web server.

I want to allow the LAN to access the website the website on the webserver.
But the Web server mustn't be able to initate connections with the LAN.

I am using the following rules but i can not make a connection.

Webserver: 172.16.10.88
LAN : 192.168.0.0/16

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 172.16.10.88 -m multiport -
-dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.10.88 -d 192.168.0.0./16  -m multiport 
--dports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: Have you enabled IP forwarding, i.e. what does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` show? Also, for your 'return' rule (the 2nd rule in your output) seems wrong: the `dport` for _return_ traffic from a webserver would generally be a dynamic port (typically 32768  to  60999) - it seems easier to just allow ESTABLISHED flows, without specifying the ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow returned packets from web server towards your LAN clients, you need to change the second rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.10.88 -d 192.168.0.0./16  -m multiport 
--sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

When response is returned, the ports 80, 443 are the source port not destination ports.

A good practice is to allow `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` traffic without any other restrictions (source, or destination) like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This rule should be placed as first one. This is fine as far as you are restricting the initiating traffic.

Comment: Just a small remark: you typed --state REALTED which obviously needs to be --state RELATED